# Sending JSON object to Web API failure

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send jQquery object through ajax to a Web API controller.

Here's my jquery code:

```
var CurrentOrder = [];
var lineItem = { 'rowid': '34', 'quantity': '4', 'comment': 'somecomment' ,
               'rowid': '22', 'quantity': '5', 'comment': 'somecomment1'};

CurrentOrder.push(lineItem);

$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    data: JSON.stringify({ SessionCart: CurrentOrder }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: '/api/Cart/UpdateCart/',
    //traditional: true,
    beforeSend: function () {
        res.container.append(res.loader);
    },
    success: function () {
        res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
        $('.loader').attr('style', 'display:none');
        GetSessionCart();
    },
    error: function () {
        res.container.find(res.loader).remove();
        $('.loader').attr('style', 'display:none');
        alert('Current Order could not be updated. Please Try again.')
    }
})
```

Here's my model:

```
 public class Cart
{
    public string rowid { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }

}
```

And the controller:

```
    [HttpPut, HttpDelete]
    [ActionName("UpdateCart")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateCart([FromUri] List<Cart> SessionCart)
    {

       //do sth
    }
```

The problem is the controller gets hit but the parameter `SessionCart` count is always 0. I have tried not to stringify the object, using quotes to wrap the object, passing a single object and not an array and a bunch of other things. None of these worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[FromUri]` should either not be there at all or change it to `[FromBody]` -

`[FromUri]` will be looking at the querystring for the data vs the `PUT` body

Also, it looks like you should be setting your data to:

`data: JSON.stringify(CurrentOrder),`

This, plus what Matteo1010 suggests.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thanks! the problem was [FromUri] & JSON.stringify. Have a good one :D

Answer (score 1):

I think json is wrong:

```
var lineitem = { 'rowid': '34', 'quantity': '4', 'comment':     'somecomment'} ;
CurrentOrder.push(lineItem);
lineitem = { 'rowid': '22', 'quantity': '5', 'comment': 'somecomment1} ;
CurrentOrder.push(lineItem);



data: JSON.stringify(CurrentOrder),
```